# If it were that

Tags: subjunctives

*They remained the same unless it were that they aged somewhat in looks*

Is it subjuctive for indicating an unreal or unlikely situation?
Is this can be put like this?

*They remained the same unless they had aged somewhat in looks*

Comment: There, the subjunctive could be paraphrased, "though I suppose one could say that ... "

Comment: "except that they had aged" or "One could identify no change, unless it were that..." Or similar in order to establish an antecedent for "it". Also, I would say that "aged in looks" is non-idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

The past subjunctive is only used in conditional statements that are counterfactual; what you have written above doesn't appear to be conditional.

> "They remained the same unless it [was] that they aged somewhat in
>   looks."

There's no subjunctive there because you're talking about something that actually happened in the past.  In fact, I can't figure out a way to make that statement subjunctive in English and I'm a native speaker.  For instance:

> "I *would not do* anything of the sort unless I *were* specifically
>   ordered to do so by a superior."

There's an example of the past subjunctive using the subordinating conjunction **"unless"**.